# How to jump to a tab position (or equivalent) in html or css

Tags: css

I am trying to format a web-based quiz page with a sample of code containing embedded text boxes.  I would like the text boxes to be over to the right, away from the code.  The current result looks like this:
[image: T]

The code is below.  The text boxes are where the user should enter the answers, but I want them shifted over to the right.  I originally tried to do this using two div boxes, but that has its own problems that are even worse.  This way, the text boxes are on the same line as the code, guaranteed.

I tried span, using css to set a big width, or perhaps setting the left edge.  Ok, I was wrong, it doesn't work.

The first question is how to achieve this.  The second is that in order to see what was going wrong, I set the background color of the span to be something ugly. As you can see, the color of the span in css seems to continue through to the next line.  Is this a bug?  The behavior is the same in firefox and IE10.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Weird Div Placement Problem</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles3.css" media="all"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="bg">
      <div class="content">
    <div class="bounds">
      <div class="question">
        <a name="q10"/><span class="number">10.</span>
        Please fill in the values indicating what will be computed by the program.
      </div>
      <div class="code">
void loop() {
<br/>  int a = 1;
<br/>  int b = 2;
<br/>  int c = a+b;  <span class="rc"/> //c = <input type="text" name="a10c" size="10"/>
<br/>  int d = c / 3; <span class="rc"/> //d = <input type="text" name="a10d" size="10"/>
<br/>  int e = 7 / 2; <span class="rc"/> //e = <input type="text" name="a10e" size="10"/>
<br/>}
      </div>
    </div>
      </div>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the css:

```
div {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}

div.bg {
    background-color: #4040A0;
    width: 800px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

div.code {
    width: 55%;
    spacing: 0px;
    background-color: red;
    color: black;
    font: normal 16pt Verdana, fixed;
}

span.rc {
    left: 400px;
    background-color: #d00040;
}

div.bounds {
    background-color: #202090;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font: normal 15pt/18pt Arial;
}

.number {
    font: bold 24pt Arial;
    margin: 10px;
}

text{
    font: normal 14pt verdana;
}
```

Ok, so FakeRainBrigand suggested I use clear: both and float: right.
I believe I did what you asked, but I will repost the code.  This is similar to what happened before with two div boxes.  There is some really bad behavior.  Basically the two div boxes do not stay on the same line even though it would seem they should.  Here's the image (same on firefox, but this is IE10).

[image]
The new css is:

```
div {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}

div.bg {
    background-color: #4040A0;
    width: 800px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

div.code {
    width: 55%;
    spacing: 0px;
    background-color: red;
    color: black;
    font: normal 16pt Verdana, fixed;
}

div.q {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    font: normal 12pt Verdana, fixed;
}
/*
div.rc {
    float: right;
    display: block;
}

span.rc {
    left: 400px;
    background-color: #d00040;
}*/

div.bounds {
    background-color: #202090;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font: normal 15pt/18pt Arial;
}

.number {
    font: bold 24pt Arial;
    margin: 10px;
}

text{
    font: normal 14pt verdana;
}
```

and the html is:

Weird Div Placement Problem
    
  
  
    
      
    
      
        10.
        Please fill in the values indicating what will be computed by the program.

void loop() {

int a = 1;

  int b = 2;

  int c = a+b;  //c = 
  int d = c / 3; //d = 
  int e = 7 / 2; //e = 
}

```
  </div>
```

Comment: Did you try `float: right` on the input elements?

Comment: What were the problems of using multiple divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `float` and proper HTML you can push the comment to the right side of the box.

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/myVxT/)

[image: example of the result]

```
<form class="code">
    <div>void loop() {</div>
    <div>int a = 1;</div>
    <div>>int b = 2;</div>
    <div class="q">int c = a+b;<span class="rc" />//c =
        <input type="text" name="a10c" size="10" />
    </div>
    <div class="q">int d = c / 3;<span class="rc" />//d =
        <input type="text" name="a10d" size="10" />
    </div>
    <div class="q">int e = 7 / 2;<span class="rc" />//e =
        <input type="text" name="a10e" size="10" />
    </div>
    <br/>}
</form>
```

And in addition to your current CSS, use this:

```
.q { clear: both; }
.q .rc { float: right; display: block; }
```

Comment: answer looks good, and I'm trying it now, but I'm still curious why a span is affecting color wrapping to the next line when it clearly doesn't go to the next line.

Comment: Yes, this does work!  Sorry, at first I missed that you weren't using inner div boxes at all.  What I don't understand is how nested div boxes cause the mayhem you see in the question, but this solution works

Comment: You had some tags that weren't closed, or were closed with the wrong tag.

Comment: fixed that, it makes no difference

Answer (score 0):

How's this

http://jsfiddle.net/vVM2C/

**HTML**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Weird Div Placement Problem</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles3.css" media="all"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="bg">
      <div class="content">
    <div class="bounds">
      <div class="question">
        <a name="q10"/><span class="number">10.</span>
        Please fill in the values indicating what will be computed by the program.
      </div>
      <div class="code">
void loop() {
<br/>  int a = 1;
<br/>  int b = 2;
<br/>  int c = a+b;  <span style="margin: 0 0 0 3.4em;" class="rc"/> //c = <input  type="text" name="a10c" size="10"/>
<br/>  int d = c / 3; <span style="margin: 0 0 0 3em;" class="rc"/> //d = <input  type="text" name="a10d" size="10"/>
<br/>  int e = 7 / 2; <span style="margin: 0 0 0 2.9em;" class="rc"/> //e = <input  type="text" name="a10e" size="10"/>
<br/>}
      </div>
    </div>
      </div>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}

div.bg {
    background-color: #4040A0;
    width: 800px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

div.code {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    spacing: 0px;
    background-color: red;
    color: black;
    font: normal 16pt Verdana, fixed;
}

span.rc {
    left: 400px;
    background-color: #d00040;
}

div.bounds {
    background-color: #202090;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font: normal 15pt/18pt Arial;
}

.number {
    font: bold 24pt Arial;
    margin: 10px;
}

text{
    font: normal 14pt verdana;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Floating to the right will eventually be a solution:

```
  input {
    float: right;
  }
```

but this won't work currently because the text is all a single block, with BR tags being used to put them on separate lines. You need to put each line in it's own container, a DIV or P (paragraph).

By the way, you have an unnecessary closing FORM tag which should be removed.

Comment: Sorry, that's me cutting this out of a larger program and doing a messy job of it!